# Rethinkbd changefeeds for flutter dart

Tags: flutter, dart, rethinkdb, real-time-data, rethinkdb-python

I am using rethinkdb in my app. I can insert and retrieve data using the "rethink_db_ns" package. But I need to get data in real-time. for that, I am using This method

```
Future<void> getData(RethinkDb r, Connection connection) async {
   var data = await r.table('users').run(connection);
   List list = data.toList();
   print(list);
   getData(r,connection);
}
```

this method getting data continuously. I don't want to get the same data continuously like this. I want it only when data changes into the database. is there any better way to get changefeed.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by this method :

```
Future<dynamic> changeFeed(RethinkDb r, Connection connection)async{
print('running async.....');
var result = await r
    .table('tab_users')
    .changes()
    .run(connection).then((value) {
      print(value);
      Feed val = value;
      val.forEach((element) {
        print(element);
      });
});
```